# How to check if a char in string is a digit?

Tags: python

I have tried `string_name.isdigit`, but it return true even if `string_name = "+"`.
So how to check if a char is a exactly digit and not signs of mathematical operations

Comment: `string_name = "+"; print(string_name.isdigit())` prints false for me

Comment: Show us a code sample demonstrating the issue!

Comment: im sorry. i forgot about (). my VS even didn't underscored that mistake. thanks

Comment: why would it underscore it? its an attribute so its valid from a syntax point of view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are not calling `isdigit` as a method. you need to put `()` after it

```py
string_name = "+";

if string_name.isdigit:
    print("its a digit")
else:
    print("not a digit")

if string_name.isdigit():
    print("its a digit")
else:
    print("not a digit")
```

**OUTPUT**

```
its a digit
not a digit
```